# Extracting a string between two Delimiters

Tags: java, string

I have a String called

```
ID: 17. Name: Milky way. City: Riverview. Date: 2017-03-21 00:00:00.0
```

I need to take only the Name which is "Milky way".

This is what i've tried so far

```
tempString1.substring(tempString1.indexOf("Name:"), tempString1.indexOf("."));
```

which gives me index out of bounds -2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use offset when looking for the dot, otherwise it searches from the start of the string and matches the dot in `17.`.

```
String label = "Name: ";
int start = tempString1.indexOf(label) + label.length();
String name = tempString1.substring(start, tempString1.indexOf(".", start));
```

Comment: That makes sense, thank you! However it is returning Name: Milky way, How could i make the Name: go away?

Comment: Ah, another bug. `indexOf` gives you the index of the start of the substring, so you need to add its length. I'll edit my answer.